# Dynamically adding scrollbar to flex component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, scroll, scrollbar, mxml

I have been stuck on this for far too long. I think it's simple so I must be misunderstanding something. Any help/pointers is appreciated.

I have a spark form components laid out like

label1:   textbox1
label2:   textbox2
label3:   textbox3 etc

I want these to display across the full width of my flash app. When I shrink the width of the flash player I want a scrollbar to appear. At the moment no scroll bar is appearing.

My code is:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="left" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
</s:layout>

<s:BorderContainer borderVisible="false">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Form id="custAccountForm" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="-10" paddingLeft="-15" paddingRight="-45"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:FormHeading label="Customer/Account Details"/>
        <s:FormItem label="CustomerName">
            <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Account">
            <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Currency">
            <s:ComboBox id="currencyCB" width="100%"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="Account Balance">
            <s:TextInput width="100%" maxChars="24"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

How do I get a vertical/horizontal scroll bar on this to only appear when the application is smaller that the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSb04c7610c3432839-13869d09121418556f1-7ffc.html).  The Flex 4.0 Spark Architecture does not bake scroll bars into the containers like they did with the Halo/MX style controls.  Conceptually you may do something like this:

```
<s:Scroller width="200" height="200">
 <s:Group width="100%" height="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

 <s:BorderContainer borderVisible="false">
...
    <s:Form id="custAccountForm" height="100%">
..
    </s:Form>
 </s:BorderContainer>
 </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

In my usage I find that the Scroller works best if given an explicit height and width; and if given percentage height and widths will size to it's content--meaning you have no scroll bars.  If you need to hanle he browser changing size; you'll have to change the scroller's height and width when the container changes.  Possibly using updateDisplayList() to resize.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Flextras. I have tried to add what you suggested with the scroller. I want to have it so that the scroller does not appear until the browser size is made smaller. The updateDisplayList only gets called though on start up. Not when the browser/flashplayer changes size. How can I get it to do this? I have code but am unsure where to post it in this questions.

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: updateDisplayList gets called every time the screen renderers.  I'm not sure what you may have done in code so that it only gets called on startup.  You should be able to listen to a resize event and invalidaeDisplayList() inside that resize event.  If you have additional code, you should edit your original question and add it, there.  The code you posted in your deleted answer does not call "super.updateDisplayList()" which I'm sure would cause all sorts of issues.

Comment: Thanks Flextras. I will try the super.updateDisplayList() at some point and see if that helps. I will also checkout the invalidate commands you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: just realised that clipAndEnableSCrolling in the example should be clipAndEnableScrolling. With a small c in scrolling. Minor issue that the compiler picks up. Solution works really well though!